# requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission() error?

Tags: android

I think ever since the newest Android update this method:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
    document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
    cursor.close();

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + " = ? ", new String[]{document_id}, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
    cursor.close();

    return path;
}
```

wont work because i need some kind of permission. is there a fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hold the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. That involves:

- putting the appropriate `<uses-permission>` element in your manifest, and
- if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, [requesting the permission at runtime](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) from the user, as those permissions are `dangerous`