# I'm trying to display media from the user's phone but my app keep crashing

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I'm asking for permissions and I have logged my program and can see that the permission is granted so it should work.
I'm displaying the images inside a recycler view, and when I swipe down and return back, my app crashes. It also happens if I try to move to another activity that uses that photo.

This is the error:                                                                                                     `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A1000067180 from pid=29739, uid=10242 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

The code I'm using to check for permissions is:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672338/java-lang-securityexception-permission-denial-reading-com-android-providers-me](https://stackoverflow.com)

The pictures are saved in a List and are displayed using an adapter:

```
// onBindViewHolder: Binds data to the views in each ViewHolder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsListAdapter.PostViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (posts != null) {
            final Post current = posts.get(position);
            holder.tvAuthor.setText(current.getAuthor());
            holder.tvcontent.setText(current.getContent());
            holder.ivPic.setImageURI(current.getPic());
            holder.ivProfile.setImageURI(current.getProfile());
            holder.tvLikes.setText(String.valueOf(current.getLikes()));
         }
}
```

I described above :)

Comment: Which permissions are you talking about? And what is Android version of used device?

Comment: `current.getProfile()` Should we know which value that would have? And also you did not tell when you obtained that uri. It can be obtained a month ago i think.

Comment: `The pictures are saved in a List ` Do you mean: "the uris of the pictures are save in a list"? Or what exactly?

Comment: `I swipe down and return back, my app crashes.` Dont let your app crash by catching that exception. You can displat a Toast() then to the user displaying e.getMessage();

Comment: `requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs` Well... if that is the message you are supposed to tell us how you obtained the used uris i think dont you think so?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html